# Mlflow Error 1: Invalid experiment ID: '.ipynb_checkpoints'. Error2: deleted a folder under MLflow directory - it doesn't work now

Tags: tracking, mlflow

Mlflow Error 1: Msg: Invalid experiment ID: '.ipynb_checkpoints'.

On Mac computer2, I did the following code in the noon and it worked correctly. When I re-run it 8hours later without changing it, shows Invalid experiment ID: '.ipynb_checkpoints'. Appreciate any direct advise for resolution? state checkpoint issue? how do I resolve this?

---

import mlflow

EXPERIMENT_NAME = "mlflow-DecisionTree13"
EXPERIMENT_ID = mlflow.create_experiment(EXPERIMENT_NAME)

#Tracking log

for idx, d in enumerate([5,10]):
for idx1, M in enumerate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]):
xxxx
xxxx

```
    # Start MLflow
    RUN_NAME1 = f"run_{idx}{idx1}"
    with mlflow.start_run(experiment_id=EXPERIMENT_ID, run_name=RUN_NAME) as run:
        # Retrieve run id
        RUN_ID = run.info.run_id

        # Track parameters
        mlflow.log_param("d",5)
   
        # Track metrics
        mlflow.log_metric("accuracy", accuracy)

        # Track model
        mlflow.sklearn.log_model(clf, "classifier")
```

---

Error2: on MAC computer1, I deleted a folder under MLflow directory. the MLflow designated host/browser now shows  error: please find GitHub for help.  I encounter error running ML code in Jupiter lab. I uninstall and reinstall Mlflow library in jupterlab, reinstall anaconda, all doesn't work. Used Computer 2, it work. Any advise how to resolve computer 1's Mlflow issue?

new to Mlflow, your adv is much appreciated.

Error1: no resolution. seems more like a checkpoint state issue.

Error2:
uninstalling Mlflow and reinstalling it. doesn't work.
created the folder with same name in the same Mlflow directory, nope
reinstalling anaconda - haven't tried this.
on fresh computer 2, clean installation it work. But how do I resolve computer 1 issue ?